# Click on expand sign if it contains certain text

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have html like below I want to click on `expand sign` if it contains name `test`

```
<tr class="testclass">
<td class="sign" rowspan="1"><img src="/Expand.png" value="+" alt="expand"></td>
<td class="name" rowspan="1">test</td>
<td id="6">test</td>
```

I tried `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr/td/img')` This will give me sign but I can't tell if it's associated with `test`
I also tried `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr/td[contains(.,'test')]')` But how do I get `sign` from that and click on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible XPath expression :

```
//tr[td[@class='name' and contains(.,'test')]]/td/img
```

The XPath basically locate `tr` elements where `td` child has `class` attribute equals `"name"` and contains text `"test"`. And then return the corresponding `td/img` from such `tr`.